# Crunch wordlist

Tags: passwords, dictionary

I am trying to set up a wordlist of 8 character words where:

- the first letter is a capital 'WXCVBN'
- the next three are lower case 'wxcvbn'
- the next three are numbers between '123456'
- the last character has to be '*' or '!'.

I've been trying for the last hour to make it work properly going through the man pages and threads. But I can't seem to be able to get it to work.

`crunch 8 8 + WXCVBN + wxcvbn + 123456 + *! -t,@@@%%%^`

This is the last command I've tried. The capital letter works, and it knows which ones needs to be capital, lowercase, numbers. But at the second character, it starts from 'a'.

Example output: Wbpf557w

Anyone can help me with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How about adding a bit of context so we know what you're talking about? Also, this isn't really a security question. You're just asking us to solve a specific non-security problem (You're either asking about an algorithmic problem or you want instructions on how to use a specific wordlist creation program).  Please ask elsewhere (Super User Stack Exchange might be a place to go).

Comment: @Pascal because it's `crunch` it is possible for it to be on-topic here. This is generally one of the better phrased `crunch` questions we get.

Comment: @Lor what do you mean by "But at the second character, it starts from 'a'."

Comment: I'm not going to disagree with someone who has 38k reputation, though I'm tempted :-)

Comment: @schroeder first of all, thanks for cleaning up the post a bit. To get on topic again, by that phrase I mean that crunch is going through the whole alphabet instead of the lowercase 'wxcvbn', as you can see in the output I've posted within the thread. Now I've tried to fix that by trying to do the same as the examples from the crunch man pages, but can't seem to make it work properly. Any idea what I am doing wrong that it doesn't stick to the predefined letters/number/special?

Comment: @Pascal feel free to disagree! This is a community-run site and as a mod, I uphold the community values (both Sec.SE and SE at large). I'm just saying that this one is pretty good.

Comment: @Lor your example has a valid letter in the 2nd space. It's the 3rd and 4th and last places that are not within your expected set. Your template seems off to me. Can you verify `-t,@@@%%%^`? Did you insert a space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the + wrong. From the man pages it looks like you should have the command as

```
crunch 8 8 wxcvbn WXCVBN 123456 *! -t,@@@%%%^
```

Edit: To explain: 
The + sign means default character set. Crunch wants the character sets defined in the order as lower case, upper case, numbers, symbols. Your original command had 8 character sets defined due to the plus signs and surprisingly crunch did not complain. What you actually asked for was "Use all lower case characters, use only WXCVBN for upper case characters, use all numbers, use only wxcvbn as symbols." It ignored the remaining character sets.